# How to make Try/catch stripe error handler send user to success.php if no errors occurred?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am setting up a checkout page for my business, I`m using Stripe API for this. I am having issues with my charge.php file not redirecting when no errors are returned by the error handler.

I've tried using the header() function which does successfully redirect if I enter the right card details, but when I try with one of the cards used for displaying an error message, it just redirects to index.html where the input form is located. If I remove the header function, charge.php will successfully display the errors, but obviously, there will be no redirect on a successful charge.

```
  // added stripe dependencies with composer
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('SECRETKEY');

 // Sanitize POST Array
 $POST = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

 $first_name = $POST['first_name'];
 $last_name = $POST['last_name'];
 $email = $POST['email'];
 $token = $POST['stripeToken'];

// Create Customer In Stripe
try {
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "email" => $email,
  "source" => $token
));

// Charge Customer

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 4999,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "description" => "Online Purchase",
  "customer" => $customer->id
));

//ERROR HANDLER
} catch ( Stripe\Error\Base $e ) {
  // Code to do something with the $e exception object when an error occurs.
  echo $e->getMessage();

  // DEBUG.
  $body = $e->getJsonBody();
  $err  = $body['error'];
  echo '<br> ——— <br>';
  echo '<br>YOU HAVE NOT BEEN CHARGED — <br>';
  echo '— Status is: ' . $e->getHttpStatus() . '<br>';
  echo '— Message is: ' . $err['message'] . '<br>';
  echo '— Type is: ' . $err['type'] . '<br>';
  echo '— Param is: ' . $err['param'] . '<br>';
  echo '— Code is: ' . $err['code'] . '<br>';
  echo '<p>If you have entered the correct details, please try DOMAIN (in Safari or Chrome). If the error persists, please screenshot this message and send it to me alongside your email address.</p>';
  echo '<br> ——— <br>';

// Catch any other non-Stripe exceptions.
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $body = $e->getJsonBody();
    $err  = $body['error'];
    echo '<br> ——— <br>';
    echo '<br>Error — <br>';
    echo '— Status is: ' . $e->getHttpStatus() . '<br>';
    echo '— Message is: ' . $err['message'] . '<br>';
    echo '— Type is: ' . $err['type'] . '<br>';
    echo '— Param is: ' . $err['param'] . '<br>';
    echo '— Code is: ' . $err['code'] . '<br>';
    echo '<p>If you have entered the correct details, please try DOMAIN (in Safari or Chrome). If the error persists, please screenshot this message and send it to me alongside your email address.</p>'; 
    echo '<br> ——— <br>';
}

header('Location: success.php?tid='.$charge->id.'&product='.$charge->description);
```

I expect the charge.php to redirect to success.php on a successful charge and to display the errors on a faulty charge.

Comment: what is stopping you to redirect from try block.. is not your success condition fulfilled there?

Comment: I do not know if this is related, but you should be using a fully qualified namespace for classes in your catch Stripe\Error\Base should be \Stripe\Error\Base and Exception should be \Exception

Comment: @pwaterz - The OP is already using fully qualified namespaces. You only need to prefix them with a back slash if you're using them under another namespace, which this code doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does the redirect because it's after the `catch` blocks. Those blocks get executed and because there is no `return` statement in there, it will go on and execute the next line after the block(s) - your redirect header line.

You can either:

1. Move the `header(....)` line into your `try` block, just after the charge creation
2. Do a specific `return` or `exit` type of line in your `catch` blocks.

Both are viable solutions.